# php in free(): error: chunk is already free

Tags: php, shell, cron, imap

I have developed a script that uses php's `imap_search` and when it gets to the stage of finding the emails with the function `imap_search()` i get a error being produced

> php in free(): error: chunk is already
>   free
>   Abort trap: 6 (core dumped)

This script requires to be run through a cron, But when it does it does that above error and seems to abort the script, If i run from the browser it has this error inside the error logs but still runs the script in full.

Below is the line it is failing on:

```
$this->mailbox_emails = imap_search($this->mailbox_stream,'ALL');
```

Comment: Check your php.ini files. Often there is a different config setup for apache and command line execution. There might be some differences between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an internal php error. [File a bug](https://bugs.php.net/) on the imap module (if you want it fixed fast, include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Also note that this is a memory corruption issue, which is usually caused (long) before it is noticed. Therefore, the `imap_search` function is probably not the buggy one; the `imap_*` function you used just before it is a good candidate.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response, This actually makes sense and i will file a bug report and hope that they can respond.

For now i will do a hack that will run on a browser and load the file as that does error but still works as it should.